# Checkbox setState:0 on app launch

Tags: xcode, oop, checkbox, delegates

I'm having a problem with a checkbox. I want to set it to 0 (unchecked) on app launch, but the checkbox is controlled by another class "myClass" for example.

Here's what I did:

- I opened Interface Builder and put a checkbox (NSButton) in my window, dragged NSObject in my MainMenu.xib window, renamed it to say "myClass". Added an outlet called "myCheckbox" (NSButton) and linked it to the checkbox I created earlier. Finally, I added some things.

Here's the code for my myClass.m:

```
#import "myClass.h"

@implementation myClass

- (void) changeState
{
    [myCheckbox setState:0];
}

@end
```

myClass.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSButton *myCheckbox;
}

- (void) changeState;

@end
```

Then I made some changes in the AppDelegate files so they execute some things when the app is launched:

```
#import "UntitledAppDelegate.h"
#import "myClass.h"

@implementation UntitledAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    myClass * someClass = [[myClass alloc] init];

    [someClass changeState];
}

@end
```

UntitledAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface UntitledAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

The purpose (if this works) is to set a value to the check box depending on the setting stored in the Defaults file.

The problem might be easy or too simple but I'm only a beginner...

Some help would be appreciated, Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [myCheckbox setState:0];
}
```

in myClass.m solved it.